# Resize image from internet

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, firebase, swift2, xcode7

My app retrieves an image from URL, but I need to change the image size before it appears on the user interface in my **tableview**.

Here is my `tableViewController` code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Alamofire



class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var postField: MaterialTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var imageSelectorImage: UIImageView!


var posts = [Post]()
var imageSelected = false
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

static var imageCache = NSCache()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    postField.delegate = self

    //tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400
    //tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension



    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self


    DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.queryOrderedByChild("timestamp").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        self.posts = []
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {
                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let key = snap.key
                    let post = Post(postKey: key, dictionary: postDict)
                    self.posts.insert(post, atIndex: 0)
                }
            }

        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

  }
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


/**
 * Called when the user click on the view (outside the UITextField).
 */
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(true, moveValue: 167)
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(false, moveValue: 167)
}

func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){
    let movementDuration:NSTimeInterval = 0.1
    let movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration )
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0,  movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    print(post.postDescription)

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as? PostCell {
        cell.request?.cancel()
        var img: UIImage?
        if let url = post.imageUrl {
            img = FeedViewController.imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage
        }

        cell.configureCell(post, img: img)
        return cell
    } else {
        return PostCell()
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imageSelectorImage.image = image
    imageSelected = true
}

@IBAction func selectImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func makePost(sender: AnyObject) {
    //TODO: Add loading spinner while data is being processed
    if let txt = postField.text where txt != "" {
        if let img = imageSelectorImage.image where imageSelected == true {
            let urlStr = URL_IMGSHACK
            let url = NSURL(string: urlStr)!
            //FIXME: Add error handling
            let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2)!
            let keyData = API_KEY_IMG.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let keyJSON = "json".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            Alamofire.upload(.POST, url, multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imgData, name: "fileupload", fileName: "image",
                    mimeType: "image/jpg")
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: keyData, name: "key")
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: keyJSON, name: "format")

                }) { encodingResult in

                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                            if let info = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                            if let links = info["links"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                                if let imgLink = links["image_link"] as? String {
                                        print("LINK: \(imgLink)")
                                        self.postToFirebase(imgLink)
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        })
                    case .Failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                   }
           }

        } else {
            self.postToFirebase(nil)
        }
   }
}

func postToFirebase(imgUrl: String?) {
    var post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
        "timestamp": NSNumber(longLong: currentTimeMillis()),
        "description": postField.text!,
        "likes": 0
    ]

    if imgUrl != nil {
        post["imageUrl"] = imgUrl!
    }

    let firebasePost = DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.childByAutoId()
    firebasePost.setValue(post)

    postField.text = ""
    imageSelectorImage.image = UIImage(named: "camera")
    imageSelected = false
    tableView.reloadData()
    postField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func currentTimeMillis() ->Int64 {
    let nowDouble = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    return Int64(nowDouble * 1000)
}

}
```

and here is my custom cell:

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var showcaseImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var likesLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var likeImage: UIImageView!

var post: Post!
var request: Request?
var likeRef: Firebase!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "likeTapped:")
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    likeImage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    likeImage.userInteractionEnabled = true

}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImage.frame.size.width / 2
    profileImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 2
    profileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    self.profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
    self.showcaseImage.clipsToBounds = true

}

func configureCell(post: Post, img: UIImage?){
    self.post = post
    likeRef = DataService.ds.REF_USERS_CURRENT.childByAppendingPath("likes").childByAppendingPath(post.postKey)
    self.descriptionText.text = post.postDescription
    self.likesLabel.text = "\(post.likes)"

    if post.imageUrl != nil {

        if img != nil {
            self.showcaseImage.image = img
        } else {

            request = Alamofire.request(.GET, post.imageUrl!).validate(contentType: ["image/*"]).response(completionHandler: { request, response, data, err in

                if err == nil {
                    let img = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    self.showcaseImage.image = img
                    FeedViewController.imageCache.setObject(img, forKey: self.post.imageUrl!)
                } else {
                    print(err.debugDescription)
                }

            })

        }

    } else {
        self.showcaseImage.hidden = true
    }

    likeRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if let doesNotExist = snapshot.value as?
            NSNull {
            //This mean we have not liked this specific post
            self.likeImage.image = UIImage(named: "heart-empty")
        } else {
            self.likeImage.image = UIImage(named: "heart-full")
        }

    })
}

func likeTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    likeRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if let doesNotExist = snapshot.value as?
            NSNull {
            self.likeImage.image = UIImage(named: "heart-full")
            self.post.adjustLikes(true)
            self.likeRef.setValue(true)
        } else {
            self.likeImage.image = UIImage(named: "heart-empty")
            self.post.adjustLikes(false)
            self.likeRef.removeValue()
        }
    })
}

}
```

Here is an example showing what I want to achieve:

[this when user post the portrait image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvrpt.jpg)

[this when user post the landscape image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNN1J.jpg)

In summary, I want the image width to fit the width of the device screen, and the height of the uiimage to be dynamic, regardless of the image orientation (landscape or portrait).

Comment: The question is a little unclear. Given an image of some size, when you assign it to a NSImage;  let image = NSImage(imageLiteral: "Enterprise.png"), and then assign the image to an imageView;  myImageView.image = image. It will auto-re-size to fit within the size of the NSImageView; the width will fill horizontally and the vertical being variable.

Comment: @Jay hai Jay, im sorry because my english is very bad, but this is my problem, im successfully retrieve image from internet and displaying in my tableviewcell, and store in the cache if that data is uiimage, but my problem is, that image data is string, the problem is i want that image converted to an actual image first before displaying in my tableviewcell, but i have no idea to do that. Because i need to resize it first

Comment: So, is the question is how to convert a image, stored as a string in firebase to a UIImage and then resize it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this part, where 300x600 is needed size of your image to save.

```
let image = UIImage(data: data!)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(300, 600))
image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 600))

let smallImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```